Homer Simpson Labeling Everything In The Kitchen
I'm looking for an episode of The Simpsons in which Homer labels all items in the kitchen including all eggs each.
He also blends all their spices to form a super spice which than is used by the cat as a litter box.
Can anyone tell me the name of this episode?

For reference I found it using this transcript. It's S21E23 "Judge Me Tender" at 10 minutes.

Homer: Now that I have all this free time, I thought I would do you a huge favor. 
Marge: That's nice. What kind of favor? 
Homer: I organized the kitchen. I labeled everything with a labelmaker.


Read more at: http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=431&t=22325

Good. But you should add more details to your answer, such as a video clip or transcripts.

Thanks for fixing it for me. I was just about to do the same!
